# Background Image Stretch On Homepage

Tags: html, css, twitter

I'm currently trying to make my background image on my homepage to stretch across the whole page, but I'm having difficulties doing this because when I try and re-size the window it becomes smaller?

this is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
            body{
                background: url(img/phantom410.jpg); repeat-y;
                background-size:cover;
                background-color:black;
            }
        </style>
```

Is there a way I can get an image for my website homepage and stretch it across the whole page like what twitter does with their background image; but not have it shrink once it starts getting smaller? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body { 
  background: url(https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
h1{
  color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Full Background</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center><h1>Full Background Image</h1></center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! Worked like a charm!!

Comment: You welcome @CaelanGrgurovic! Help others by accept it as right answer. :)